# z80 Assembly nested loops

Tags: assembly, imperative-programming, z80

I need to write three nested loops in Assembly on a z80 hardware.
The first loop (the most internal one) should iterate 70 times, the other two 100 times.

This is the code I have come up with, but it seems not to work properly; it iterates until an interrupt is generated (Stack-Overflow error, I think).

```
loop1:
ld a, 46h
   loop2:
   ld b, 64h
      loop3:
      ld c, 64h
      dec c
      jnz c, (loop3)
   dec b
   jnz b, (loop2)
dec a
jnz a, (loop1)
halt
```

A similar code in C++ would be

```
for(int b = 100; c>0; c--)
   for(int c = 100; b>0; b--)
      for(int a = 70; a>0; a--)
       ...
```

Comment: You sure you want to be initializing the loop registers inside the loops rather than outside? Seems this code will probably just appear to hang running in infinite loops since you decrement, compare, start loop reset value in register.

Comment: Try `ld a, 46` then `loop1:`,  `ld b, 64` then `loop2:`, `ld c, 64` then  `loop3:` . Also unsure why you reverse the order of the loops between your C++ and your assembler code. In assembler C would be on the outside, B in the middle, and A on the inside.

Comment: It is also unclear why you use what seem to be hex values in assembler as decimal. I could understand 46H (70 decimal), 64H(100 decimal) but you use 46 decimal and 64 decimal. Seems to me you should use 46H and 64H or just use decimal 70 and 100.

Comment: What's the `c` in `jnz c, loop3`? similarly other `jnz` instructions? In each case, the previous `dec` instruction sets or clears the `Z` flag.

Comment: @WeatherVane : I saw that too, but then was thinking he was using some bizarre pseudo-op that translates to a cmp and jp. I came to that idea (and now I think I was in error, and you are right) because I am unsure how this would even compile. A and B as far as I know aren't even flags on Z80. Either way it could be coded as a  jp nz, addr (after the dec)

Comment: @MichaelPetch the `a` and `b` and `c` in those `jnz c, loop3` etc. instructions seems to refer to the `a` or `b` or `c` which was recently decremented.

Comment: Can you tell us what Z80 assembler you are using?

Comment: @MichaelPetch actually I am programming the z80 through direct binary input (using a series of 8 buttons to represent the 8-bit binary data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you initialize loops:

```
ld a, 46
loop1:
   ld b, 64
   loop2:
      ld c, 64
      loop3:
      dec c
      jnz c, loop3
   dec b
   jnz b, loop2
dec a
jnz a, loop1
halt
```

Comment: @MWiesner : Thanks for editing my answer. I spent some time trying to make like this but could not.

Comment: no problem. Hope, you learned from it and can apply this within future questions or answers.

Comment: arent these loops backwards? according to c++ code the most external loop should iterate 100 times.

Comment: the need itself decides which loop should come first. I usually put inner loops the highest (with less code) to get better execution time.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `djnz` command for looping:

```
   ld b,46
loop1:
   push bc
   ld b,64
loop2:
   push bc
   ...
   pop bc
   djnz loop2
   pop bc
   djnz loop1
```